# PHP extract timestamp from variable and modify

Tags: php, regex

I have a PHP variable that at first glance looks like serialized data, but on checking it does not appear to be valid..

```
O:30:"myschedule":1:{s:41:"myschedule_timestamp";s:10:"1547735354";}
```

I am trying to modify the timestamp but keep the rest intact, what is my best approach?

Should I be looking at regex or something similar?

Comment: You should unserialize it, update it, and serialize it again if necessary. Though it seems to be invalid serialized data, unserialize() rejects it.

Comment: It looks like the serialized object has been corrupted by a string replacement. Corrected to `O:10:"myschedule":1:{s:20:"myschedule_timestamp";s:10:"1547735354";}` it would deserialize fine. The `10` instead of `30` is the length of the class name `myschedule`, and the `20` instead of `41` is the length of the property name `myschedule_timestamp`. Most likely the original class and property names were much longer.

Comment: XY Problem, ask yourself why its no longer valid, not how can it be hacked (mutilated) again. How do you expect to get the value out? More regex?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone More vague questions for the rest of us to answer :-)

Comment: All taken on board, I will pull the offending code apart and see if I can work out why it is being mangled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_replace` seems like a viable option here.  We can match your serialized string using the following pattern:

```
(.*")\d+(".*)$
```

Then we can piece together the updated string as we insert the new timestamp (I used `NEW_ID` below for emphasis, but presumably this would be some number).

```
$input = 'O:30:"myschedule":1:{s:41:"myschedule_timestamp";s:10:"1547735354";}';
$input = preg_replace('/(.*")\d+(".*)$/', '$1NEW_ID$2', $input);
echo $input;

Hello, world! O:30:"myschedule":1:{s:41:"myschedule_timestamp";s:10:"NEW_ID";}
```

### Demo

Comment: Just a note that since the original serialized form had the timestamp as a string, the `s:10` refers to the string length; if the new string has a different length, failing to update that would result in (further) corruption.

Comment: @IMSoP There's a smell here...the OP should backtrack, change the source metadata, and regenerate this string.  I'll leave this up just in case this helps the OP.